# latex - colorbox in caption as legend - how to center or alternative solution?

Tags: floats, legend

I have an image of a diagramm that I want to use as a source in my work. I have no possibility to create this diagram. So, I want to add colorboxes in the caption as a legend.

here is my actual code. The problem is that the `colorbox` is not centered with the text. Does somebody know how to change the orientation?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[hb]
    \begin{center}
        %\vspace{-10pt}
        \includegraphics[scale = 0.8]{images/RunningTime}
    \end{center}
    %\vspace{-10pt}
    \caption{Pattern of participants \protect\fcolorbox{green}{green}{\protect\rule{0pt}{1pt}\protect\rule{1pt}{0pt}}\protect\quad X, \protect\fcolorbox{orange}{orange}{\protect\rule{0pt}{1pt}\protect\rule{1pt}{0pt}}\protect\quad Y, \protect\fcolorbox{black}{black}{\protect\rule{0pt}{1pt}\protect\rule{1pt}{0pt}}\protect\quad Z after  }
    \label{fig:cha_HAC_RunningTime}
    %\vspace{-10pt}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please edit your document to make it compilable: Small hint: `\includegraphics` ;-)

Comment: Thanks, it is nice to be here. I just added `\usepackage{graphicx}` Is this suffcient or do you prefer to add `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` so that everybody can compile it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use `\rule{1ex}{1ex}` embedded in `\textcolor`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\legendsquare}[1]{%
  \textcolor{#1}{\rule{1ex}{1ex}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[hbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image}

\caption{Pattern of participants \legendsquare{green}~X,
  \legendsquare{orange}~Y,
  \legendsquare{black}~Z after}
\label{fig:cha_HAC_RunningTime}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Having a personal command allows you to tune up the side of the square by just acting in one place.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works amazing. Just added your lines and it has the advantage that I don't need another math package that could interfere with the work I have already done. Implemented it 1:1! Amazing!

Answer (score 2):

A quick and dirty solution with `\filledmedsquare` symbol from the `MnSymbol` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[hb]
  \begin{center}
    % \vspace{-10pt}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{images/RunningTime}
  \end{center}
%   \vspace{-10pt}
   \caption[Text for LoF]{Pattern of participants \Large\textcolor{green}{$\filledmedsquare$} \normalsize X, \Large\textcolor{orange}{$\filledmedsquare$}
\normalsize Y, \Large\textcolor{black}{$\filledmedsquare$} \normalsize Z}%
  \label{fig:cha_HAC_RunningTime}
  % \vspace{-10pt}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Christian,

thanks a lot for that quick reply. I just changed my document, but didn't get the desired result. I got the following error message: Undefined control sequence. ...$\filledmedsquare$} \protect\normalsize Z}"... ahh for sure I forgot the math package ... my fault, let me check this fast

Comment: @luftfahrt: It works for me, apparently, otherwise I could not have generated that screen shot

Comment: That is amazing. I just changed my used packages and inserted your code and received the desired result.
My only problem is now that my image is gone. I just have a black image like you. Recently I checked my folder, but all documents are still there?

@Christain Hupfer: Ahh thanks a lot, have overlooked that you added [emo] to graphicx. Now all is working fine! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You don't need a `math` package (what should that be at all?)

Comment: When I run your code for the `$\filledmedsquare$` it was necessary to add a `math`package to compile it without errors. When I afterward copied the code into my project I got different errors, because there were two `math` packages. Clearly overlooked it, that in this environment, my `math` package would be sufficient. But now it works fine, so thanks a lot!

Comment: @luftfahrt: Well, the strange thing is, that I don't need a math package at all ;-)