# Patterned legend in caption

Tags: floats, color, captions, legend, pattern

This is a follow-up question of: [latex - colorbox in caption as legend - how to center or alternative solution?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249255/latex-colorbox-in-caption-as-legend-how-to-center-or-alternative-solution)

For convenient sake, I copy the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\legendsquare}[1]{%
  \textcolor{#1}{\rule{1ex}{1ex}}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[hbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{Pattern of participants \legendsquare{green}~X,
  \legendsquare{orange}~Y,
  \legendsquare{black}~Z after}
\label{fig:cha_HAC_RunningTime}
\end{figure}    
\end{document}
```

The colored legend is now indicated in the caption. The boxes are filled with green, orange and black colors.

**Question**: How do you put some pattern in the colored box, e.g. a diagnal hatch pattern, dotted pattern etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace your command with TikZ. If you want to keep the command definition simple, the coloring commands get slightly more complicated.

You could add `draw` to the squares with patterns to show the square aspect.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\legendsquare}[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(a.south)]{\node[#1, inner sep=.8ex, outer sep=0] (a) {};}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{Pattern of participants \legendsquare{fill=green}~X,
    \legendsquare{pattern=north west lines}~J,
    \legendsquare{pattern=dots}~W,
    \legendsquare{fill=orange}~Y,
    \legendsquare{fill=black}~Z after}
\label{fig:cha_HAC_RunningTime}
\end{figure}    
\end{document}
```